# php try catch not working properly

Tags: php, try-catch, file-get-contents

I have code like this:

```
try {   
    $providerError = false;
    $providerErrorMessage = null;
    $nbg_xml_url = "http://www.somesite.com/rss.php";
    $xml_content = file_get_contents($nbg_xml_url);
    // ... some code stuff
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $providerError = true;
    $providerErrorMessage = $e -> getMessage();
    $usd = 1;
    $rate = null;
    $gel = null;
} finally {
    // .. Write in db 
}`
```

and problem is that, when `file_get_contents` can not read url (may be site not responding or something like this..) my code writes error: `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!` and execution goes direct to finally block bypass catch block without entering in it..

any ideas?

Comment: The exception, if thrown, is being handled inside your method call, and therefore, not passed up to the caller, i.e. this code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an empty error handler to prevent the warning and afterward throw a custom exception in case of failure. In this case I would write a custom `file_get_content` like so:

```
function get_file_contents($url) {

    $xml_content = file_get_contents($url);

    if(!$xml_content) {
        throw new Exception('file_get_contents failed');
    }

    return $xml_content;
}
```

and would use it in your block:

```
set_error_handler(function() { /* ignore errors */ });

try {   
    $providerError = false;
    $providerErrorMessage = null;
    $nbg_xml_url = "http://www.somesite.com/rss.php";

    $xml_content = get_file_contents($nbg_xml_url); //<----------

    // ... some code stuff
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $providerError = true;
    $providerErrorMessage = $e -> getMessage();
    $usd = 1;
    $rate = null;
    $gel = null;
} finally {
    // .. Write in db 
}
```

Then remember to restore the error handler calling:

```
restore_error_handler();
```

Note that when using your own error handler it will bypass the

> error_reporting

setting and all errors included notices, warnings, etc., will be passed to it.

Comment: Your welcome, If you think my answer helped you, please up vote or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml_content = file_get_contents($nbg_xml_url);
```

The function file_get_contents does not throw an exception. Thus an exception will not be thrown if as you say the file is not found.

From the docs:

> An E_WARNING level error is generated if filename cannot be found...

This function returns the read data or FALSE on failure. So you could check if $xml_content is FALSE ($xml_content === false) and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a php code for catching any error or exception.

Throwable is the base interface for any object that can be thrown via a throw statement, including Error and Exception.

This will catch fatal errors too. Without throwable it will not catch fatal errors.

```
    try {
     // Code that may throw an Exception or Error.
    } catch (Throwable $t) {
     // Executed only in PHP 7, will not match in PHP 5.x
    } catch (Exception $e) {
     // Executed only in PHP 5.x, will not be reached in PHP 7
    }
```

Comment: To make it a good answer, please explain it